# asymptotic estimate of $\sum 1/(k^2 H_k)$ where $H_k$ is the harmonic series

Tags: asymptotics

I  need some help here. I started with
$$\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{1}{k^2 H_k}=\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{1}{k^2  \int_0^1\frac{1-x^k}{1-x}dx}=\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{1}{\int_0^1 k^2 \frac{1-x^k}{1-x}dx}$$

But I do not know how to continue anymore.

Comment: Given that the sum converges, I'm not sure what "asymptotic estimate" would mean, apart from computing the limit... Anyway, do you have any reason to suppose that this has some simple solution?

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Note that [Harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) have a nice asymptotic estimate
$$H_n\approx\ln n+\gamma+o(1)$$
where $\gamma\approx 0.5772156649$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant). Moreover for $n\geq 1$,
$$\frac{1}{2}<H_n-\ln n\leq 1.$$

Comment: am I right in thinking that it follows that $\Sigma_{k=1}^N \frac{1}{k^2 * H_k} < \Sigma_{k=1}^N \frac{2}{(1+2 \ln k )k^2 }$? Am I too stupid to have this thinking? I am really lost.

Comment: @kylexy Your inequality is fine. Since the series $sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2 H_k}$ is convergent, you can estimate the sum. What are you exactly looking for?

Comment: I am looking for the asymptotic estimate, so I figured that I should look for the value of the finite sum... I don't know if i am on the right track.

Comment: Am I right to conclude that $\Sigma_{k=1}^N \frac{1}{k^2  H_k}$ is convergent because the $$lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}  \frac{2}{(1+2 \ln k) k^2 }=0$$?

Comment: @kylexy No, it is convergent because $1/k^2/H_k\leq 1/k^2$ and $\sum 1/k^2$ is convergent.

Comment: @Robert Z Am I right to conclude that the asymptotic estimate to this problem is O(1/k^2)?

Comment: @desperatemuch The asymptotic estimate of $1/(k^2H_k) $ is $O(1/k^2/\ln(k))$ (or $O(1/k^2)$). The series is convergent.